# Dynamically extending django models using a metaclass

Tags: python, django, model, extend, metaclass

## The Problem

I am trying to build a framework that automatically extends model classes with additional fields. Here is a short summary of what I am trying to do:

Given a model class

```
class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

I automatically want to generate a class with an additional field per class field yielding a class similar to the following:

```
class PizzaGenerated(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    name_new = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    price_new = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

as you can see, for each of `Pizza`'s properties, an additional field with the `_new` suffix has been added.

I need my solution to work irregardless of the Model's structure. In particular, I am looking for a way that allows the replication of `ForeignKey`-Fields

## My Approach

The above example of extending the `Pizza` class is solvable with the following code:

```
class ResMetaclass(models.base.ModelBase):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):​
        fields = {
            k: v for k, v in attrs.items() if not k.startswith('_') and isinstance(v, models.Field)
        }
​
        attrs_extended = {
            **attrs,
            **{fieldname + '_new': fieldtype.clone() for fieldname, fieldtype in fields.items()}
        }
​​
        bases = (models.Model,)
        clsobj = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs_extended)
​
        return clsobj

class EntityBase(models.Model, metaclass=ResMetaclass):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
​
class Pizza(EntityBase):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

The `Pizza` class is extended successfully by the `EntityMetaclass` metaclass.

## The Problem with that

Unfortunately, the above code fails, when the model contains a `ForeignKey`-Field, yielding the following backtrace:

```
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/niklas/dev/pyflx/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/niklas/dev/pyflx/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/niklas/dev/pyflx/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/niklas/dev/pyflx/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home/niklas/dev/pyflx/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/niklas/dev/pyflx/mig/models.py", line 20, in <module>
    class Contact(EntityBase):
  File "/home/niklas/dev/pyflx/pyflx/models.py", line 17, in __new__
    **{fieldname + '_patch_value': fieldtype.clone() for fieldname, fieldtype in fields.items() if fieldname != 'id'},
  File "/home/niklas/dev/pyflx/pyflx/models.py", line 17, in <dictcomp>
    **{fieldname + '_patch_value': fieldtype.clone() for fieldname, fieldtype in fields.items() if fieldname != 'id'},
  File "/home/niklas/dev/pyflx/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 492, in clone
    name, path, args, kwargs = self.deconstruct()
  File "/home/niklas/dev/pyflx/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 856, in deconstruct
    name, path, args, kwargs = super().deconstruct()
  File "/home/niklas/dev/pyflx/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 583, in deconstruct
    swappable_setting = self.swappable_setting
  File "/home/niklas/dev/pyflx/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 374, in swappable_setting
    return apps.get_swappable_settings_name(to_string)
  File "/home/niklas/dev/pyflx/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 288, in get_swappable_settings_name
    for model in self.get_models(include_swapped=True):
  File "/home/niklas/dev/pyflx/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 178, in get_models
    self.check_models_ready()
  File "/home/niklas/dev/pyflx/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 140, in check_models_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tricky!

The problem there is that when you try to `.clone` the field in the models, they have not being fully initialized, and thus, Django mechanisms of finding a foreign-model by its string qualifeid name can't be used. The problem is that the code does not check if the foreignmodel is passed as an class reference, instead of a string.

The only way to workaround this seems to be monkey-patching these checks when the classes are being created. 
While at that, when clonning a foreign-object field, the related_field - a backreference created automatically by django ORM so one can get from the "pointed-at" object to the "holder" object have to be passed explicitly to the new, cloned, field. Else it would point to the original field instead.
This requires a bit more of monkeypatching, to insert an explicit "related_name" parameter in the inner workings of the `.clone` call.

Those 2 things being acomplished, it seems to work. Here is is the code I used, based on yours:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.fields import related
from unittest.mock import patch

class ResMetaclass(models.base.ModelBase):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):

        fields = {
            k: v for k, v in attrs.items() if not k.startswith('_') and isinstance(v, models.Field)
        }
        new_fields = {}
        for field_name, field in fields.items():
            new_field_name = field_name + "_new"
            if not isinstance(field, related.RelatedField):
                new_fields[new_field_name] = field.clone()
            else:
                real_deconstruct = field.deconstruct
                def _deconstruct():
                    name, path, args, kwargs = real_deconstruct()
                    kwargs["related_name"] = new_field_name
                    return name, path, args, kwargs

                with patch("django.apps.registry.apps.check_models_ready", lambda: True):
                    field.deconstruct = _deconstruct
                    # Assume foregnKeys are always within the same file, and
                    # disable model-ready checking:
                    new_fields[new_field_name] = field.clone()
                    del field.deconstruct


        attrs_extended = {
            **attrs,
            **new_fields
        }

        bases = (models.Model,)
        clsobj = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs_extended)

        return clsobj

class EntityBase(models.Model, metaclass=ResMetaclass):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Pizza(EntityBase):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)


class MenuEntry(EntityBase):
    entry_number =  models.IntegerField()
    pizza = models.ForeignKey("Pizza", on_delete="cascade")
```

And the resulting fields on the `MenuEntry` class:

```
In [1]: from test1.models import Pizza, MenuEntry                                                                                                      

In [2]: MenuEntry._meta.fields                                                                                                                         
Out[2]: 
(<django.db.models.fields.AutoField: id>,
 <django.db.models.fields.IntegerField: entry_number>,
 <django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey: pizza>,
 <django.db.models.fields.IntegerField: entry_number_new>,
 <django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey: pizza_new>)
```